# Why won't this jQuery work in WordPress?

Tags: jquery

THIS WORKS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fadeReview() {
      jQuery(".reviewPanel     .reviewPanel2:hidden:first").fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500, function() {
    jQuery(this).appendTo(jQuery(this).parent());
    fadeReview();
    });
    }
    fadeReview();
 </script>
```

BUT, THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fadeReview() {
  jQuery(".reviewPanel .reviewPanel2:hidden:first").fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500, function() {
jQuery(this).appendTo(jQuery(this).parent());
fadeReview();
});
}
fadeReview();

function fadeReviewName() {
  jQuery(".reviewName .reviewName2:hidden:first").fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500, function() {
    jQuery(this).appendTo(jQuery(this).parent());
    fadeReviewName();
  });
}
fadeReviewName();
</script>
```

Does it have to do with running two functions?  It works ok in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/carsonmehl/VxhY6/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Won't work" doesn't say much. Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or in Chrome or Safari or IE8, use the developer tools to check for JS errors on your site.

WP3.2 now includes jQuery 1.6 and your jsfiddle example uses 1.4, so there's a possible conflict.

Comment: OK Thanks.  The fiddle works with 1.6...but I will take a look with firebug.